# How can I get my earlier DIV to not be hidden by other later DIVs?

Tags: javascript, html, css, hidden

I have a web app that is modular on the back end.

I'm trying to create a pop-up div ("new feature") notification in it.

The problem is that the module creating that DIV is executed before later modules, and as a result, the noification DIV is partially hidden by the later DIVs:

```
                       [ DATA DIV ]
                       [ //////// ]
-----------------------[ //////// ]--------------
| \\\ Notification \\\ [ //////// ] \\\ div \\\ |
-----------------------[ //////// ]--------------
                       [ //////// ]
                       [ //////// ]
                       [ //////// ]
                       [ END  DIV ]
```

Is there any way in CSS or JavaScript to do this so that the earlier notification DIV hides the later DATA DIV, not the other way around?

```
                       [ DATA DIV ]
                       [ //////// ]
-------------------------------------------------
| \\\ Notification \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\ div \\\ |
-------------------------------------------------
                       [ //////// ]
                       [ //////// ]
                       [ //////// ]
                       [ END  DIV ]
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To correctly position a DIV (or any elemnt on the page), you need to understand that the "vertical" (what is under what) positioning of elements is controlled by layers (see [W3C Visual Formatting page, #9.9: Layered presentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#layers) for details).

The layers in which a given element are in are controlled by `z-index` CSS property (available in CSS2).

To place it on top, use **higher** value (default 0).

So if your 2 DIVs had IDs `data` and `notification`, use the following style (assuming data has no style of its own with `z-index`, and assuming both can have `position: relative;`):

```
#notification {
    z-index:999;
    position: relative;
}
```

It's recommended to use a much-spaced values for z-index (e.g. 999 instead of 1) so you can easily layer many elements in between later.

*Further reading:*

- http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/z-index (has a good browser compatibility chart)
- W3C Schools (http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp)
- [W3C Visual Formatting page, #9.9: Layered presentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#layers)

Answer (score 1):

CSS should easily bring the notification div in front of everything else.

```
 div#notification {
    position: relative;
    z-index:9999; }
```

Comment: Your z-index should only reflect your real needs. A z-index of 9999 will create problems if you have a large css file with hundreds of declaration and multiple z-indexed elements...

Comment: @remibreton -- it was merely an example. the actual `z-index` could be `5` if that works.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your dynamically created `div` is absolute-positioned. Declaring `z-index:1` with css will put it on top of the other `div`s, but only if they have a lower `z-index`.

[Read more here](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/09/15/the-z-index-css-property-a-comprehensive-look/).